# Hex colour as string

Tags: string, hex

From Photoshop in Javascript, is there a good way around the problem of hex numbers with "e" in them being turned into other numbers

- ArialMT, 48, RESET DATA, 384E59

Putting them in quotation marks works, but I'd then have to do make allowances for that as well. The numbers (and other data) are exported to text files and then processed into textfiles and then imported into Excel.

Comment: Is your question whether or not it is possible to store the hexadecimal value 'e' as a decimal?  If so, then you can convert the entire hexadecimal value to any other base you want.

Comment: Where and how are the codes parsed? What are you doing?

Comment: What's the problem with `E`? Do you get any errors? What environment are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code; it's an Excel thing. You need to set the delimited text to "text" instead of "general" and then Excel won't try to mess with your hex numbers.